# Writing test for Django

Tags: django, testing

I write a small test for Django. It always return true which is not right. The code is attached below. I can not figure out why? Thanks for your help.

```
from django.tests import TestCase
from myapp.models import Content


class SimpleTest(TestCase):
    def test_add_user(self):
        cnt = Content('en', 'hello world!')
        cnt.save()
        self.assertEqual(cnt.text, 'hello world again!')
```

I make it work by creating a tests/ folder under myapp/. Then I move the test.py to myapp/tests/, I also put an `__init__.py` to the same folder. Then it works.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you defining your `Content` model?

Comment: Your code is incorrect. `django.tests` is not one of Django's modules.